# Angular 2 detect changes to a readonly input's [ngModel] binding in directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I've got this directive which sets a fluid height on a textarea depending on its content:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[fluidHeight]',
  host: {
    '(ngModelChange)': 'setHeight()'
  }
})

export class FluidHeightDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.setHeight();
  }

  @HostBinding('style.height.px')
  height: number;

  setHeight() {
    console.log(true)
    this.height = this.elementRef.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
  }
}
```

However I can't get it to work when I use `[ngModel]` along with `readonly`:

```
<textarea [ngModel]="foo" fluidHeight readonly></textarea>
```

There's another textarea which changes the content of the `readonly` input.

I've tried using `ngModelChange`, `change` and `input` but none of them seem to work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: is `foo` your content?

Comment: @Dinistro Yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A setter should do the trick:

```
export class FluidHeightDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input('fluidHeight')
    set content(content:any) {
        this.setHeight();
    }

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.setHeight();
    }

    @HostBinding('style.height.px')
    height: number;

    setHeight() {
        console.log(true);
        this.height = this.elementRef.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up with an Input that takes in the ngModel, which is basically the same solution as this. You don't need the setter to make it work actually.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz nice one :)